# Creating arrays from user input c++

Tags: c++

I want to create an array from user input. The user input will look like this:

```
ID     Numbers
1 -3 2 -1 12 19 8
2  3 1 -3 2 19 5
3  7 4 1 7 9 3
4  9 12 4 6 -7 4
```

So there is an ID and then 6 numbers after that. I could have up to 20 IDs. At first I had something like

```
struct Prog 
{
    unsigned int ID;
    signed int num_1;
    signed int num_2;
    signed int num_3;
    signed int num_4;
    signed int num_5;
    signed int num_6;
};
```

And I read in the data files as input in a separate function from the terminal using this:

```
for (;;)
{
cin >> Temp.ID >> Temp.num_1 >> Temp.num_2 >> Temp.num_3 >> Temp.num_4 >> Temp.num_5 >> Temp.num_6;
}
```

However, the problem is, when I try to find the min/max values of these IDs/Arrays, it became very confusing with that many different arrays and elements.

So now what I want to do is something like this:

```
struct Prog 
{
    unsigned int ID;
    static const int num_elements = 6;
    signed int numbers[num_elements];

};
```

And then later on I can find the min/max value easier by doing 1 for loop and comparing the values using 1 if statement instead of many as would be in my previous example.

My problem is, I am not sure how to take the above new Struct and read the data file at the top given and store them in the program to run operations on them. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Without using vector from std or min/max from std.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I don't want to use the std.

Comment: Without using anything from std? Then do not use `cin`!

Comment: Learning the fundamentals for class I suppose.

Comment: This is probably some sort of homework guys.  Just trying to keep it simple and civil.  At least there is code to work with and not just a "give me my codzz plz kthnxbye" type response...

Comment: If he doesn't know enough fundamentals to be able to read a few values from a file, with correct error checking, he shouldn't have seen C style arrays yet, or the course is doing things backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for (;;)
{
cin >> Temp.ID >> Temp.numbers[0] >> Temp.numbers[1] >> Temp.numbers[2] >> Temp.numbers[3] >> Temp.numbers[4] >> Temp.numbers[5];
}
```

or perhaps

```
while(1)
{
  cin >> Temp.ID;

  for(int i = 0; i<Temp.num_elements; i++)
  {
    cin >> Temp.number[i];
  } 
}
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but it gives you some info at least.

Comment: For my struct, I get this error so I can't test your code fully yet : ISO C++ forbids initialization of memebrs 'elements'. And for the while I get an error expected unqualified id before while.

Comment: Em, where is 'elements' defined in my code or yours?  There is a num_elements, but not an elements.  Was there a forgotten _ perhaps?  Oh, try changing your const num_elements to static const.  That might fix this for you.

Comment: Num_elements equals elements in my code, sorry for the confusion. The static fixed it, but what did it do exactly? Now I only have the while error.

Comment: static tells the compiler that it's okay to assign the value at compile time and that it will never, ever change.  There's more to it than that, but that's the best way to describe it for now.  It basically makes it a type safe #define.  Now which while error?

Comment: before the while(1) line I had the code Prog Temp;, and it gave 2 errors, then I removed it and now it only gives this error for while(1): expected initializer before 'while'.

Comment: Notice I was missing a semi-colon on the first cin.  Double check that, then check to see if there is a missing brace or semi-colon above the loop in your code.

Comment: Hmm must be something else in my code, ill tinker around with it and see if it works, then i can choose it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the number of elements can change, the simplest
solution would be to use `std::vector`:

```
struct Prog
{
    int id;
    std::vector<int> num;
};
```

Second, the usual way of reading into an object is using `>>`.
In this case, however, you have no real delimiters, so any 
`operator>>` will not know where to stop.  The next best
solution is to have a constructor which takes a string, and
count on your client to know how to delimit the input.
Something like:

```
Prog::Prog( std::string const& toParse )
{
    std::istringstream parser( toParse );
    parser >> id;
    if ( ! parser ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "no id" );
    }
    int element;
    while ( parser >> element ) {
        num.push_back( element );
    }
    if ( ! parser.eof() ) {
        //  Format error, before running out of data
        throw std::runtime_error( "format error" );
    }
}
```

Since this is a constructor, the only way of reporting an error
is an exception.  (And it should probably be `explicit`.)

Finally, since you may want to create more than one, and your
actual input is line oriented:

```
std::string line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    ++ lineNumber;
    try {
        data.push_back( Prog( line ) );
    } catch ( std::runtime_error const& error ) {
        std::cerr << error.what() << " (line " << lineNumber << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Because you don't know how many to expect here either, `data`
should be an `std::vector<Prog>`.  (Even if you do know how many
to expect, I'd use an `std::vector'.)

Comment: And he turns this in to his CS101 professor and gets an F  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan If so, it's time for him to change schools.  A professor which downgrades someone because they do error checking or encapsulation is doing more harm than good, and should be forbidden to teach.

Comment: Ah, but I'm willing to bet that he wouldn't be able to explain in detail what is written above.  Turning in something that you have no idea on how it operates is cheating.  The idea is to learn something, not copy from elsewhere with no idea on how it works.  try/catch and all the internals of std:in you are using probably wouldn't be taught for years.  It's a great example on a professional level solution, but not for homework...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I agree that he shouldn't just copy it and turn it in.  The idea is that the example will show him the tools available to solve his problem, not that it would solve it for him.  Fir example, in simple cases like his, when dealing with a POD, I'll sometimes skip the constructor, and just put the code to parse the line directly in the `while` loop.  But the basic principles rest: read line by line, check all input for errors, etc.